# Is it well designed relational database just with one table?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, rdbms

I have MySQL database containing just one table, having 100 rows and 12 columns: ID (primary key), NAME, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, TYPE, COUNTRY, CONTINENT, DESCRIPTION_PATH, STORY_PATH, PICTURE_PATH, ICON_PATH and VIDEO_PATH. Do you think it is OK to keep all the data in one table or should data be distributed within more tables?

Comment: I recommend reading up on [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to take the guesswork out of schema design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfectly fine table design as long as your Name rows only need at most one description, one story, one picture, one icon, and one video.

As soon as you want someone to have two pictures, you'll need to create another table for pictures and store one picture per row, each one referencing your first table.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Pictures (
  picture_id INT,
  name_id INT,
  picture_path VARCHAR(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (picture_id, name_id)
  FOREIGN KEY (name_id) REFERENCES Names (id)
);
```

And you'd remove the picture_path column from first table of course.

Comment: PICTURE_PATH is an URL link to the folder in my file system. Inside this folder, there are 5 pictures defined for every row which I am retrieving one by one from the database in Java application.  But I guess this is not what you really meant, is it? For every single row I have just value of each column. So I guess it should be OK...

Comment: Yes, if you have just one picture *path* per row, then that's OK.

Comment: One small question - how do I call the database containing just one table? Can I call it relational database still?

Comment: Sure, that's fine.  "Relational" does not mean "relationships" between tables.  It means the table is a [relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitary_relation), in the mathematical sense.